# Cron Job Restart Node Process every 4 hours

Tags: node.js, cron

when I want to stop a node script I usually use `CTRL+C`. Is it possible to make CronJob automatically stop it for me? 
(i want cronjob to use `node .` and after 4 hours to exit the node process and use `node .` again).

if possible, how? (an example video or script would help me a lot)

Let me know if you need more information on this, even though it's pretty much self explanatory, but I suck at giving explanations and information.

Comment: Do you mind explaining why you need to auto-restart your application?

Comment: how will that help you give me an answer to my question @artfulbeest

Comment: An altenative way of accomplishing what you need to accomplish with auto-restart, sometimes it works magic to zoom out on a problem

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to run your node application with a process manager like [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/), this will ensure your application keeps running when you need it running.

Then you will create a cron job to run after every four hours and execute a script than will stop and start your application. If you are using linux and pm2, you can use script below

```
#!/bin/bash
#app.sh
echo 'stopping <pm2-app-id>'
pm2 stop <pm2-app-id>
echo 'stopped <pm2-app-id>'
echo 'strting <pm2-app-id>'
pm2 start <pm2-app-id> 
echo 'started <pm2-app-id>'
```

Then register cron job with `crontab -e`

```
0 0,4,8,12,16,20 * * * PATH=$PATH:<full path to pm2>:<full path to node bin> <full-path-to-app.sh>/app.sh
```

Important to add full path to pm2 and nodejs executable above, otherwise crontab will not be able to find them.

Comment: Thanks! How should I create this script? (Where do I put it?) (the pm2 stop pm2 start one)

Should I make a .sh file?

Comment: yeah..put it in a .sh file.

Comment: and i'll have to run it? If yes, how?

Comment: Install pm2, run your application with it. Then get app name or app id from pm2 status, create .sh file using above script and replaving pm2-app-id with app name from pm2 status. finally add entry to cron job using  using crontab -e and entring cron task provided above -

Comment: Understood, but how do i run the sh script. Like, do I use something to run it or there's a commandline

Comment: So after you create the script, you make it executable (chmod +x script.sh), then on terminal crontab -e and add cron entry to file that will be opened. here is the the cron entry 0 0,4,8,12,16,20 * * * PATH=$PATH:<full path to pm2>:<full path to node bin> <full-path-to-app.sh>/app.sh, make sure to replace full paths  with paths actual paths

Comment: When setup is done, cron job will run the sh script every four hours, and sh script when run will stop then start your application